# Can't access variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I have the following source code:

```
var labeled_pic = new Array();
var testing;
function get_label_pic(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost/advanceSearch/index/getlabelpic",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, data){
                labeled_pic[key] = data;
            });
            testing = "testing";
        }
    });
};
get_label_pic();
console.log(labeled_pic);
```

And then I call those function using `get_label_pic();`, after that I want to access `labeled_pic` array using `labeled_pic[3]` but it's return `undefined`. I use firebug, and I try to write this `console.log(labeled_pic)`, and it's return:
[image: Firebug result]
How can I access the labeled_pic variable,.?

Comment: when are you accessing labeled_pic variable? it will be filled with values after response comes from server - after your success function executes.

Comment: its because of the asychronous behavior of $.ajax

Comment: put the console.log statement after  testing = "testing"; It should work as expected

Comment: @Zango I'll access it in img tag,.

Comment: @Zango this is when I use the variable: `$("#result").append("<img src='" + labeled_pic[3] +"' />");`

Comment: First thing printed in Console is an empty array, then number, string pairs. Are you sure that first [] is not the one that related to "labeled_pic"?

Comment: you must execute that code in your success function at the end. I've posted code sample in answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are making an asynchronous call (the AJAX request) so your JavaScript continues and doesn't wait for the call to come back.

So the call to `get_label_pic()` will take no time at all and your code will continue straight to the `console.log(labeled_pic)` (which won't be set yet, because the `success` callback in your AJAX call won't have finished.

If you want to us it, then you'll need to put your code into your AJAX success, or call another function from it:

```
function get_label_pic(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost/advanceSearch/index/getlabelpic",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, data){
                labeled_pic[key] = data;
            });
            testing = "testing";

            console.log(labeled_pic); // this will show the values
            callmyOtherFunction(); // To call something else
        }
    });
};
get_label_pic();
console.log(labeled_pic); // This will be undefined
```

What actually happens is this:

1. Creates the function get_label_pic
2. Calls `get_label_pic()`

   1. Makes the ajax request
3. Calls `console.log`
4. Script is at the end
5. Some time passes, then the server response comes back

   1. Iterates through the data, setting `labeled_pic[key]`
   2. Sets `testing = 'testing'`
   3. Calls `console.log(labeled_pic);`
   4. Calls `callmyOtherFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

As your ajax call is asynchronous, there is a great chance that you will try to read the array, before the ajax-call is completed. If you you create a callback-function to be triggered when the ajax-call is complete, and put your code within that callback, then you are sure that the ajax-call is complete, before you are trying to access the array.

```
function get_label_pic(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost/advanceSearch/index/getlabelpic",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, data){
                labeled_pic[key] = data;
            });
            testing = "testing";
        },
        complete: doWhatYouWantToDo()
    });
};

function doWhatYouWantToDo()
{
   alert(labled_pic[3]); // <!-- now the array is populated
}
```

Comment: is this function below will work,.? `function doWhatYouWantToDo()
{
   labeled_pic[3] = "stat.png";
}
`

Comment: @Praditha With that function, you would replace what was stored in labled_pic[3] by the ajax-call with stat.png. Is that what you want to accomplish?

Comment: ya, but I still can't store ajax result to labeled_pic where the labeled_pic is global variable,.

Comment: @Praditha I'm afraid I don't understand how you mean. Since you declare var labeled_pic = new Array(); outside both get_label_pic and doWhatYouWantToDo, the variable is accessible within both functions. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The function is a closure and hence labeled pic has fallen out of scope.

If you pass it as a parameter to your callback function it will be encapsulated in the closure and available at the time the callback is executed .

HTH

Comment: may you give me an example please,.:)

Comment: This isn't a scope problem. `labeled_pic` is a global variable and will be in scope inside the callback. The problem is that the code that assigns a value to it is executed after the `console.log` because it's asynchronous.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  `labeled_pic` is a global variable, no?

Comment: Anyway, without seeing the whole javascript, how can we know the variable is global as it was declared with `var`. Maybe this piece of code is encapsulated within another function.

Comment: @DidierG. - True, we don't know that it's global, but it's certainly in scope inside the callback, whether it's global or not. If the code in the question is a snippet from inside a larger function, the variable won't be global but it will still be accessible from inner functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call console.log(labeled_pic); inside the success callback of the $.ajax

```
...
 success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, data){
                labeled_pic[key] = data;
            });
            testing = "testing";
            //here call the console.log
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you must execute that code at the end of success function, so your code must look like this:

`var labeled_pic = new Array();
var testing;
function get_label_pic(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost/advanceSearch/index/getlabelpic",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, data){
                labeled_pic[key] = data;
            });
            testing = "testing";`

```
        $("#result").append("<img src='" + labeled_pic[3] +"' />");

    }
});
```

};
get_label_pic();